# Disable CSS concatenation in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

Is there a way to disable CSS concatenation in Symfony2 for production?

I think that this concatenation messes up the files and @import statements no longer work on production, only on the dev environment.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Assetic to manage your css files, you need to use the cssrewrite filter and use the notation `bundles/acmebundle/css/yourfiles.css"` instead of `@AcmeBundle...` when you add your files to the stylesheets block. With the @AcmeBundle notation, the paths inside the stylesheets are not rewritten correctly.

For this to work, you need to install the assets of your bundles previously using the command `php app/console assets:install --symlink`

You'll find the details here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html#fixing-css-paths-with-the-cssrewrite-filter